# correctly configuring nested resources with shallowing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've ran into my first issue with nested resources, and from the documentation

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting

I'm not entirely able to figure out how to make sense of this, and how to apply it correctly to my situation, currently my things are setup like this:

```
  resources :stores do
    resources :locations do
      resources :business_hours
    end
  end
```

now I'd like to limit the nesting, the way they recommend but I'm uncertain on how to achieve this, as locations belongs to stores, and business hours belongs to locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the rails documentation is essentially saying is that with your resource configuration above you'll have a url that will look something like this on your web page.

`mywebapplication.com/stores/1/locations/1/business_hours/1`

with the corresponding rails helper method for your code

`stores_locations_business_hours_url`

Now there isn't really anything wrong with that and you can do it this way but you'll start to run into tedious problems especially with your business_hours controller. The reason being is because for your controllers you will have to pass in every @model object preceding the following. You'll have to do something like

`stores_locations_business_hours_url([@store,@location,@business_hour])`

to access a page. To limit that you will need to do something like this:

```
resources :stores do
    resources :locations, shallow: true
end

resources :locations do
    resources :business_hours
end
```

So now instead of `mywebapplication.com/stores/1/locations/1` the url will like this `mywebapplication.com/locations/1` and now your business hours url will be one level deep. That's what is meant by the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To go with what Rails wants you doing, all you have to do is add `shallow: true` to each of your nested `resources`:

```
resources :stores do
  resources :locations, shallow: true do
    resources :business_hours, shallow: true
  end
end
```

This produces, as they put it, "routes with the minimal amount of information to uniquely identify the resource", which look like this:

```
                    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                          Controller#Action
   location_business_hours GET    /locations/:location_id/business_hours(.:format)     business_hours#index
             business_hour GET    /business_hours/:id(.:format)                        business_hours#show
           store_locations GET    /stores/:store_id/locations(.:format)                locations#index
                  location GET    /locations/:id(.:format)                             locations#show
                    stores GET    /stores(.:format)                                    stores#index
                     store GET    /stores/:id(.:format)                                stores#show
```

The collection actions for `locations`, eg. `index`, get nested under `stores` because `locations` belong to `stores`, but to identify a specific location, the route references `locations/1` without the `stores/` prefix, because you don't need a `store` ID to identify the `location`.

This cascades down the tree: to identify the `business_hours` collection actions, you need the `location` the hours belong to, but because you have a `location` ID, you don't need the `store` involved, so you get `locations/:id/business_hours`. When you want a specific set of hours, you don't need the `location` anymore, so you just get `/business_hours/1`.

If you want to maintain the entire hierarchy for the hours collection paths (that is, `/stores/1/location/2/business_hours`), you need to either not `shallow` your `locations` paths, which will keep their member actions (`show`, `edit`, etc.) under `/stores/1/locations/2`, or you'll need to manually specify the paths you want using less of Rails' helpers.